# Copy documents to iOS devices via the command line

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing

I have a couple apps which I directly copy data in/out of using iTunes (iPhone->Apps->(scroll down) File Sharing. Once there you can drag/drop, but I'd really like to be able to automate this process.

Is there any way to copy new "Documents" into an App on my iPhone via the command-line without using the iTunes GUI?

I'm dreading doing it with AppleScript, but if that's the only method so be it. My device is jailbroken if that helps, but I'd much prefer to do it with standard interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSH on the device, you can use `scp`:

```
scp /path/to/file root@iphone.local:/path/to/destination
```